# Problem solving the standard deviation for a stochastic variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables, standard-deviation

Information:

In a laboratory we have a vial of water that's being kept on 50 degrees Celsius. This is measured with the best thermometer in the world. The standard deviation on this thermometer is sigma = 2.0 degrees Celsius.

X = measured temperature in degrees Celsius. Then we have E(X) = 50.0 and Sigma = 2.0 when we measure the temperature in the water we know is 50 degrees celsius.

Y = temperature in degrees fahrenheit.

[image: equation for Y]

> Previous solved equations:
>   [image: Previous solved equations image]

*We now arrive at the problem with the stochastic variable and its standard deviation.*

We have bought in 5 thermometers and we use them all to find the temperature in the vial of water. We use the average from these to determine the temperature in the water.

[image: W equation]

You can use the rule for independent variables (which we assume our Xs are):
[image: independent variables]

**e) Calculate the standard deviation for the stochastic variable W.**

So what I thought at first could be the answer was this:
[image: First solution example for W]

The 4s I got from the solution in a) where I calculated for X. It is short for [image: x_i-bar x], which is equal to 8 on each X, because I am assuming that X = 50 and thus by using the sigma standard deviation for the thermometers I have 48, 50 and 52.

**EDIT:**
After being corrected (keeping the error for future references):
[image: Solution 2 for W]

**^This was also wrong, it should be the one which is blockquoted down below.**

But on another forum I got a suggestion that it might be the following:

> Seems like you want the standard deviation of the mean, I'm not sure
>   where the 8 plays in at all, but since the variables are independent,
>   $$S_W^2 = \text{Var}(W) = \text{Var}\left(\dfrac{1}{5}(X_1+\cdots
> > X_5)\right) = \dfrac{1}{5^2}\text{Var}\left(X_1+\cdots X_5\right) $$
>
> $$=\dfrac{1}{25}\sum_{i=1}^5 \text{Var} \left(X_i\right)
> > =\dfrac{1}{25}\sum_{i=1}^5 (2)^2 = \dfrac{20}{25}=\dfrac{4}{5} $$
>
> So if I interpreted this right, $S_W=2/\sqrt{5}$. Maybe wait for
>   another opinion.

BUT, I got this suggestion before I added in the rest information with the temperatures and the previous solved equations.

Thanks in advance for tips to what I can read or do to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

1. $\text{Var}(X)=4$ not $8$ so $\text{Var}(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5)=20$ not $40$
2. $\text{Var}(W)=\dfrac{\text{Var}(5W)}{5^2}$ not $\dfrac{\text{Var}(5W)}{5}$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Did a recalculation and of course you were correct, silly me and this problem. Been going forward one step and backwards 2 steps all day.

Is it possible that the stochastic variable's standard deviation is = 2 now?

Comment: You seem to have ignored my 2nd comment: $\sqrt{\dfrac{20}{5^2}}= \dfrac{2}{\sqrt5}$

Comment: I guess that was to the solution which was in the blocktext - quoted? That wasn't my doing (the equations), but I'll calculate it out. Sorry for seemingly being ignorant.

Comment: Just did the numbers - there is no issue?
Where is the issue with the root((20/5^2))=(2/root(5))?

It is there in 20/25 = 4/5 and then when it's rooted it's 2/root(5).

Comment: Sometimes you seem to be saying $S_W=2$ and sometimes $2/\sqrt5$.  The later is what you want.

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Thanks for clarifying yet again.